# Fragment with multiple views, "screens"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've been searching a way to use a Fragment with it's own "screens".

My scenario:

- FragmentActivity -> layout: tab host with these tabs: Home | Network | Feeds
- HomeFragment -> layout: with 2 buttons, I need create a screen for these buttons but I don't know how to do that, maybe hide the elements that are showing and showing only the elements that I need on the "button screen"
- NetworkFragment -> layout: n buttons and n screens too
- FeedsFragment -> layout: n buttons and n screens too

The tab host is working fine, I can switch between my tabs(fragments) but when at the fragment screen I will need click that buttons and show other screens than the fragment tab screens.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you asking for a stack of views when you say "show other screens"?

Comment: Yes @louielouie like a stack o views or the cardlayout from java Swing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to use is a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html).  This will let you have a stack of views.  Part of its documentation reads:

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top.

This is used frequently in the Android framework to do tasks like showing an empty view or a list view like in the following code snippet.  This snippet can show either a ListView or a TextView.

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <!-- Here is the list. Since we are using a ListActivity, we
         have to call it "@android:id/list" so ListActivity will
         find it -->
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

    <!-- Here is the view to show if the list is emtpy -->
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="No items."/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Note that the first element is on the bottom and the last element is on the bottom, after inflating the layout.  In this particular example, this means that the TextView will be the only one visible, since it matches parent (i.e. fills the parent.)

If you want to make the other view visible, then you can make the other view invisible:

```
findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisible(View.INVISIBLE);
```

If you have multiple views (which you called screens), just loop through them and set the ones you don't want showing to be invisible in order to show the one you do want showing.

Note that if you want to get fancier, you can do the same technique with fragments.  There is a good Android training article about this called [Building a Flexible UI](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html).  It still uses a FrameLayout, but it utilizes Fragment transactions.  It may not work in your specific case though, because fragments cannot contain other fragments and you are already relying on multiple fragments in your TabHost, so start off with the more straightforward FrameLayout method above.